# how to wait multiple asynctask to finish their work?

Tags: android, json, rss, android-volley, xmlreader

I'm using `ThreadPoolExeecutor` to make 3 Asynctask to work at the same time. Every thread collected data from a RSS feed in one `Arraylist` and then I would like to combine these 3 Arraylist into one to updated View in main  thread. The problem is I need to do this after all 3 thread finished their work, how to listen on these thread?

Answer (score 2):

Use `CountDownLatch`. This java class provides you convenient synchronized counter. Init an object with count 3, call `await()` and then call `countDown()` on it when each task is finished. Once it is 0 the lock will be released and you can perform your task.

Comment: If I call `await()` in main thread it will be blocked. So I should put `await()` in a fourth thread?

Comment: Yes. Create a thread that will call `await()`. After lock is released you can perform your action. If you need to perform UI action you can use UI handler: `public void run() {countDownLatch.await(); uiHandler.post(yourRunnable);}`

Answer (score 1):

Create a member variable and initialize to 0, increment it on every onPostExecute. Also check if the value is 3 in all onPostExecute and if it is 3 call method to combine the arraylist.

Comment: In case of concurrent modification, it's better to use `AtomicInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call async task get function which waits for it to finish or you can hold a counter where every task will increase in its onPostExecute function.  Once the counter value will be the number of async tasks, execute your code.

Comment: calling get function will block your UI until it finishes. Don't do that.